# How can I compare SQLdate and CalendarDay

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, calendar

Hi I am trying to compare Sqldate with CalendarDay and if date matches i am changing the bg color of the calendar

```
private void Calendar1_DayRender(Object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    CalendarDay de = null;

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYDB"].ToString()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Today", SqlDbType.Date));
            cmd.Parameters["@Today"].Value = e.Day.Date.;
            cmd.CommandText = " Select Date from tour where date >= @Today";

            SqlDataReader sr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            de = (CalendarDay) sr.GetValue(0);

            while (sr.NextResult())
            {
                if (e.Day.Equals(de))
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                }
                i++;
                de = (CalendarDay)sr.GetValue(i);
            }
            sr.Close();
            sr.Dispose();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format returned by sql server I think should be of DateTime format. When you compare a DateTime to a CalendarDate, you should use the [CalendarDay.Date Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendarday.date.aspx) property to compare the dates. So that for you should be comparing e.Day.Date with a DateTime.Date value returned from the database. Your database should return it's value into a DateTime variable, so you compare a DateTime against a DateTime.